# How to use Capsule on old Whmcs hooks

Tags: laravel, hook, whmcs

I have upgraded Whmcs from 6 version to 7.7 one and want to use Laravel's Capsule option instead of classic SQL syntax but i run into issues on execution.

Tried WHMCS documentations but can't seems to fetch capsule array properly.

```
<?php

/** old hook **/
add_hook('AdminClientServicesTabFields', 1, function($vars) {

$PID = $vars['id'];




        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name,mid FROM tblping where id = '$PID'");
               while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                      $var1 = $data['name'];
                      $var2 = $data['mid'];
                     }


    return [
        'var1' => $var1 ,
        'var2' => $var2,
    ];

});
```

```
<?php

/** new hook **/
add_hook('AdminClientServicesTabFields', 1, function($vars) {

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

$PID = $vars['id'];


$result = Capsule::table(tblping')->select('name','mid')->where->('id', '=', '$PID')->get();

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                      $var1 = $data['name'];
                      $var2 = $data['mid'];
                     }


    return [
        'var1' => $var1 ,
        'var2' => $var2,
    ];

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to anyone whos interested, solution is as follows:

```
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

add_hook('AdminClientServicesTabFields', 1, function($vars) {

﻿   $PID = $vars['id'];
    $result = Capsule::table('tblping')->select('name','mid')->where('id',$PID)->get();         
$array= json_decode(json_encode($result), True); 

$var1 = $array[0]['name'];
    $var2 = $array[0]['mid];

return [ 'var1'=> $var1, 'var2'=> $var2]

});﻿
```